# Display number of selected files in upload form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using

```
<input type="file" name="upload_attachment[]" class="buttonupload" multiple/>
```

to upload and process files on one HTML form.

Is there a simple way with js/jquery to display number of selected files when someone selects the files from browse button?

Comment: Yes, you can use this plugin called jQuery File Upload. It should sort out your issue. http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/. ps: there is no other way to help the user but giving to him the link for the demos. =/

Comment: This is not related to PHP. Look into the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this.files.length`:

```
$(':file').change(function () {
    $('#numberOfFiles').text(this.files.length + " files selected");
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B8ahH/)**